# Generate Column names from MySQL table in Python

Tags: python, json

Is there any way I can get the column names from my SQL select result?
Here is my little test code and all I want is to generate a sample JSON from the result:

```
import MySQLdb
...
....

cursor.execute('SELECT * from table')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
column = [t[0] for t in cursor.description]

for row in rows:
    myjson = {"id": row[column['id']], "name": row[column['name']], "age": row[column['age']]}
    myresult = json.dumps(myjson, indent=4)
    return myresult
```

But I'm getting `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str`
I don't want to use indices like so `row[2]` in case I add or remove a column from my table, it does not affect the result. I want to be able to refer to the column names.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the column names through `cursor.description`, which is a tuple of tuples. By accessing the first element of each, you get the column names.

```
column_names = [t[0] for t in cursor.description]
```

This means you can create a dict with the column names -> index mapping which would at least let you write something like

```
for row in rows:
    myjson = {"id": row[columns['id']], "name": row[columns['name']], "age": row[columns['age']]}
    myresult = json.dumps(myjson, indent=4)
    return myresult
```

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your help. I've updated the code and still getting the same error. See the code above. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hi again, I finally got it working. Thanks for the awesome pointer.